# jQuery.html() gets inner html. but i need the entire html

Tags: jquery

if i call

```
jquery("a").html()
```

i get what is INSIDE of the "a" tag

if i want the entire html, what do i call?

```
<a>xxxx</a>
```

Comment: outerHTML is by the way originated here: http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml

Answer (score 7):

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return jQuery('<div />').append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
jQuery('a').outerHTML(); // <a>xxxx</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is outerHTML and there is no direct way to get that in jQuery. You can write your own function

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $('<div>').append( this.eq(0).clone() ).html();
};

$("yourselector").outerHTML();
```

In javascript you can use outerHTML, but isn't compatible with every browser. Take a loot at **[outerHTML](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery .outerHTML() plug-in from http://darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/. To get your HTML from the matched element you need something like:

```
$("a").outerHTML();
```